# Reverse DNS and Godaddy email server, What should it point to?

Tags: smtp, godaddy, reverse-dns

We are assigned 3 static IP addresses by our ISP and lately we have been having problems delivering our mail. We checked with Cloudmark and they suggested contacting our ISP to add a reverse DNS entry for our IP addresses. Now we use Godaddy as our email server and web host and our assigned IPs are not linked to any concrete domain names.

What should the reverse DNS for our IP addresses point to? Should it point to an imaginary host name (ex. **mail.mycompanywebsite.com**), or should it point to the SMTP server of Godaddy (**smtpout.secureserver.net**) or the MX record of Godaddy (**smtp.secureserver.net**)?

Will there be a problem with the three IP addresses pointing to the same domain name?

(P.S: I am actually a programmer with very little experience in server administration so I would appreciate a not-too-complex answer :) )

Comment: Where do you host your DNS? Do you use ISP DNS service or godaddy?

Comment: I believe we are using ISP DNS (we use obtain DNS Server automatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no email is sent using your ISP assigned IP addresses, you don't really have to provide them with a `PTR` record. As I understood, you are using Godaddy to send your email so their configuration should be OK.

You must however setup an [SPF record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) in your DNS zone stating that the servers from Godaddy are allowed to send emails using your domain name.

Comment: We do not have problems using godaddy's webmail, we do however have problems sending emails using outlook which is what led us to believe that we have a problem with our IP addresses.

As for the SPF record, which domain name are you referring to? We do not have domain names linked to our IP addresses.

Comment: I'm talking about your email domain name `@example.com`. What is your exact email configuration in Outlook (what is the POP3 or IMAP server, maybe Exchange, what is configured as SMTP server)?

Comment: We don't use Exchange, the POP3 server is pop.secureserver.net and the SMTP is smtpout.secureserver.net. Our domain name @example.com is the same as our website address (www.example.com)

Comment: OK, so there is nothing related to your ISP IP addresses. Could you post the output of this two commands: `nslookup -type=TXT example.com` and `nslookup -type=MX example.com` if they can be anonymized.

Comment: Here you go:
nslookup -type=TXT aimsuae.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.1

aimsuae.com
primary name server = ns45.domaincontrol.com
responsible mail addr = dns.jomax.net
serial  = 2013041700
refresh = 28800 (8 hours)
retry   = 7200 (2 hours)
expire  = 604800 (7 days)
default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

Comment: MX NSLookup:  
nslookup -type=MX aimsuae.com  
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.1

Non-authoritative answer:
aimsuae.com     MX preference = 0, mail exchanger = smtp.secureserver.net
aimsuae.com     MX preference = 10, mail exchanger =
mailstore1.secureserver.net
smtp.secureserver.net   internet address = 72.167.238.201
mailstore1.secureserver.net     internet address = 72.167.238.201

Comment: @Spock, any updates on what I should use as my reverse DNS based on the nslookup?

Comment: @MarawanOkasha, I don't think your problem is related to your ISP IP addresse but can be a DNS configuration problem. Try to add [SPF records](https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/1125/How+can+I+point+my+e-mail+towards+GoDaddy%3F) to your DNS zone: `@ IN TXT v=spf1 a mx include:smtp.secureserver.net ~all`.

Comment: Will do, but if I want to do a reverse DNS to appease Cloudmark, what should the domain name be?

Comment: You can just use your domain name which seem to be `aimsuae.com`. You just have to choose relevant names.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, one final question though, should the domain name be a fictitious subdomain of my domain xxx.aimsuae.com (ex. mail.aimsuae.com)or should it be aimsuae.com directly?

Comment: Yes, you have to use a subdomain. You can choose whatever you want.